# Probability of hitting curve in the plane

Tags: probability, reference-request, brownian-motion, conformal-geometry

Consider the open unit disk $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and consider a Brownian motion in the plane starting at the origin. Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth planar curve such that $\gamma (s) \in \mathbb{D}$ for some $s$. Let $\text{dist} (0, \gamma) = r \in (0, 1)$, that is, the curve is always at a distance $\geq r$ from the origin. Now, fix a (small) positive real number $t$, and let $B(t)$ denote the position of the Brownian particle at time $t$.

My question is, can the probability that the particle strikes the curve $\gamma$ within time $t$ (that is, $B(s) \in \gamma, s \leq t$ be arbitrarily low? I am guessing not, but not sure. In other words, I am guessing that the probability has a lower bound independent of $\gamma$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess one could answer your question with the law of the supremum of $B_t$ over $t \in (0, \epsilon)$, for any $\epsilon > 0$. Actually due to the reflexion principle, this is known and we have (I'll do the proof in dimension 1 but it exactly the same in dimension 2). Let $S_t = \sup_{t\in (0, \epsilon)} \{ B_t \}$, then we have : 
$$
\mathbb{P} (S_t \geq a ) = \mathbb{P}(|B_t| \geq a).
$$

So now, the probability of hitting the curve of a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ (say) bounded from below by a constant $c$ is :

$$ 
\mathbb{P} (B_t \in \mathcal{C}_f \textrm{ for some $t$ before time $\epsilon$} ) \leq \mathbb{P}(S_\epsilon \geq c)
$$

where $\mathcal{C}_f$ stands for the "curve" of $f$. Now playing on $\epsilon$ and $c$ should give your answer (you know the law of $|B_\epsilon|$ which looks like a Dirac in 0 when $\epsilon$ goes to 0).

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. Does this give an upper or a lower bound?

Comment: Well I think it shows that given a curve $\gamma$ staying at distance $r$ of the origin, you can make the probability of $B_s \in \gamma$ for some $s$, arbitrarily small, granted that $s < \epsilon$ sufficiently small...

Comment: But in my question, I was fixing the time $t$ and the distance $r$, and then looking at the probability that the particle strikes the curve within time $t$. If the particle moves for a very short time, I agree that the probability can be made small. In other words, I wish to only vary the curve, and nothing else. The idea is, I want to prove that even if the curve is sufficiently "pointy" towards the origin, you still cannot lower the probability arbitrarily.

Comment: Oh, okey I see I was feeling a misunderstanding anyways. I saw «s≤t  be arbitrarily low» in your question (there's a parenthesis lacking) and it confused me, it thought t as well could be low.